# What does mean: "No DKMS packages installed: not changing Secure Boot validation state"?

Tags: apt, grub2, secure-boot, dkms

I ran `sudo apt-get update`, `sudo apt-get install` and `sudo apt-get upgrade`.
This is my output:

```
Extracting templates from packages: 100%
Preconfiguring packages ...
(Reading database ... 364719 files and directories currently installed.)
Preparing to unpack .../libperl5.22_5.22.1-9ubuntu0.6_amd64.deb ...
Unpacking libperl5.22:amd64 (5.22.1-9ubuntu0.6) over (5.22.1-9ubuntu0.5) ...
Preparing to unpack .../perl_5.22.1-9ubuntu0.6_amd64.deb ...
Unpacking perl (5.22.1-9ubuntu0.6) over (5.22.1-9ubuntu0.5) ...
Preparing to unpack .../perl-base_5.22.1-9ubuntu0.6_amd64.deb ...
Unpacking perl-base (5.22.1-9ubuntu0.6) over (5.22.1-9ubuntu0.5) ...
Processing triggers for man-db (2.7.5-1) ...
Setting up perl-base (5.22.1-9ubuntu0.6) ...
(Reading database ... 364719 files and directories currently installed.)
Preparing to unpack .../perl-modules-5.22_5.22.1-9ubuntu0.6_all.deb ...
Unpacking perl-modules-5.22 (5.22.1-9ubuntu0.6) over (5.22.1-9ubuntu0.5) ...
Preparing to unpack .../libpam-systemd_229-4ubuntu21.10_amd64.deb ...
Unpacking libpam-systemd:amd64 (229-4ubuntu21.10) over (229-4ubuntu21.9) ...
Preparing to unpack .../libudev1_229-4ubuntu21.10_i386.deb ...
De-configuring libudev1:amd64 (229-4ubuntu21.9) ...
Unpacking libudev1:i386 (229-4ubuntu21.10) over (229-4ubuntu21.9) ...
Preparing to unpack .../libudev1_229-4ubuntu21.10_amd64.deb ...
Unpacking libudev1:amd64 (229-4ubuntu21.10) over (229-4ubuntu21.9) ...
Processing triggers for man-db (2.7.5-1) ...
Processing triggers for libc-bin (2.23-0ubuntu10) ...
Setting up libudev1:amd64 (229-4ubuntu21.10) ...
Setting up libudev1:i386 (229-4ubuntu21.10) ...
Processing triggers for libc-bin (2.23-0ubuntu10) ...
(Reading database ... 364719 files and directories currently installed.)
Preparing to unpack .../udev_229-4ubuntu21.10_amd64.deb ...
Unpacking udev (229-4ubuntu21.10) over (229-4ubuntu21.9) ...
Preparing to unpack .../libsystemd0_229-4ubuntu21.10_amd64.deb ...
De-configuring libsystemd0:i386 (229-4ubuntu21.9) ...
Unpacking libsystemd0:amd64 (229-4ubuntu21.10) over (229-4ubuntu21.9) ...
Preparing to unpack .../libsystemd0_229-4ubuntu21.10_i386.deb ...
Unpacking libsystemd0:i386 (229-4ubuntu21.10) over (229-4ubuntu21.9) ...
Preparing to unpack .../systemd_229-4ubuntu21.10_amd64.deb ...
Unpacking systemd (229-4ubuntu21.10) over (229-4ubuntu21.9) ...
Processing triggers for man-db (2.7.5-1) ...
Processing triggers for ureadahead (0.100.0-19) ...
ureadahead will be reprofiled on next reboot
Processing triggers for libc-bin (2.23-0ubuntu10) ...
Setting up libsystemd0:amd64 (229-4ubuntu21.10) ...
Setting up libsystemd0:i386 (229-4ubuntu21.10) ...
Setting up systemd (229-4ubuntu21.10) ...
addgroup: The group `systemd-journal' already exists as a system group. Exiting.
[/usr/lib/tmpfiles.d/var.conf:14] Duplicate line for path "/var/log", ignoring.
Processing triggers for dbus (1.10.6-1ubuntu3.3) ...
Processing triggers for libc-bin (2.23-0ubuntu10) ...
(Reading database ... 364719 files and directories currently installed.)
Preparing to unpack .../systemd-sysv_229-4ubuntu21.10_amd64.deb ...
Unpacking systemd-sysv (229-4ubuntu21.10) over (229-4ubuntu21.9) ...
Processing triggers for man-db (2.7.5-1) ...
Setting up systemd-sysv (229-4ubuntu21.10) ...
(Reading database ... 364719 files and directories currently installed.)
Preparing to unpack .../chromium-codecs-ffmpeg-extra_71.0.3578.80-0ubuntu0.16.04.1_amd64.deb ...
Unpacking chromium-codecs-ffmpeg-extra (71.0.3578.80-0ubuntu0.16.04.1) over (70.0.3538.77-0ubuntu0.16.04.1) ...
Preparing to unpack .../cups-bsd_2.1.3-4ubuntu0.6_amd64.deb ...
Unpacking cups-bsd (2.1.3-4ubuntu0.6) over (2.1.3-4ubuntu0.5) ...
Preparing to unpack .../cups-client_2.1.3-4ubuntu0.6_amd64.deb ...
Unpacking cups-client (2.1.3-4ubuntu0.6) over (2.1.3-4ubuntu0.5) ...
Preparing to unpack .../cups-core-drivers_2.1.3-4ubuntu0.6_amd64.deb ...
Unpacking cups-core-drivers (2.1.3-4ubuntu0.6) over (2.1.3-4ubuntu0.5) ...
Preparing to unpack .../cups-daemon_2.1.3-4ubuntu0.6_amd64.deb ...
Warning: Stopping cups.service, but it can still be activated by:
  cups.socket
Unpacking cups-daemon (2.1.3-4ubuntu0.6) over (2.1.3-4ubuntu0.5) ...

Processing triggers for libc-bin (2.23-0ubuntu10) ...
Processing triggers for man-db (2.7.5-1) ...
Processing triggers for ureadahead (0.100.0-19) ...
Processing triggers for ufw (0.35-0ubuntu2) ...
Processing triggers for systemd (229-4ubuntu21.10) ...
Processing triggers for install-info (6.1.0.dfsg.1-5) ...
Processing triggers for gnome-menus (3.13.3-6ubuntu3.1) ...
Processing triggers for desktop-file-utils (0.22-1ubuntu5.2) ...
Processing triggers for bamfdaemon (0.5.3~bzr0+16.04.20180209-0ubuntu1) ...
Rebuilding /usr/share/applications/bamf-2.index...
Processing triggers for mime-support (3.59ubuntu1) ...
Processing triggers for hicolor-icon-theme (0.15-0ubuntu1.1) ...
Processing triggers for update-notifier-common (3.168.9) ...
flashplugin-installer: processing...
flashplugin-installer: downloading http://archive.canonical.com/pool/partner/a/adobe-flashplugin/adobe-flashplugin_20181205.1.orig.tar.gz
Get:1 http://archive.canonical.com/pool/partner/a/adobe-flashplugin/adobe-flashplugin_20181205.1.orig.tar.gz [30,5 MB]
Fetched 30,5 MB in 19s (1.564 kB/s)                                            
Installing from local file /var/lib/update-notifier/package-data-downloads/partial/adobe-flashplugin_20181205.1.orig.tar.gz
Flash Plugin installed.
Processing triggers for libglib2.0-0:amd64 (2.48.2-0ubuntu4.1) ...
Setting up perl-modules-5.22 (5.22.1-9ubuntu0.6) ...
Setting up libperl5.22:amd64 (5.22.1-9ubuntu0.6) ...
Setting up perl (5.22.1-9ubuntu0.6) ...
Setting up libpam-systemd:amd64 (229-4ubuntu21.10) ...
Setting up udev (229-4ubuntu21.10) ...
addgroup: The group `input' already exists as a system group. Exiting.
update-initramfs: deferring update (trigger activated)
Setting up chromium-codecs-ffmpeg-extra (71.0.3578.80-0ubuntu0.16.04.1) ...
Setting up libcups2:amd64 (2.1.3-4ubuntu0.6) ...
Setting up libcups2:i386 (2.1.3-4ubuntu0.6) ...
Setting up libcupsimage2:amd64 (2.1.3-4ubuntu0.6) ...
Setting up cups-common (2.1.3-4ubuntu0.6) ...
Setting up cups-client (2.1.3-4ubuntu0.6) ...
Setting up cups-bsd (2.1.3-4ubuntu0.6) ...
Setting up libcupsmime1:amd64 (2.1.3-4ubuntu0.6) ...
Setting up cups-daemon (2.1.3-4ubuntu0.6) ...
Setting up cups-core-drivers (2.1.3-4ubuntu0.6) ...
Setting up cups-server-common (2.1.3-4ubuntu0.6) ...
Setting up libcupscgi1:amd64 (2.1.3-4ubuntu0.6) ...
Setting up libstdc++6:amd64 (5.4.0-6ubuntu1~16.04.11) ...
Setting up libstdc++6:i386 (5.4.0-6ubuntu1~16.04.11) ...
Setting up libcupsppdc1:amd64 (2.1.3-4ubuntu0.6) ...
Setting up libpoppler58:amd64 (0.41.0-0ubuntu1.10) ...
Setting up poppler-utils (0.41.0-0ubuntu1.10) ...
Setting up libgs9-common (9.26~dfsg+0-0ubuntu0.16.04.3) ...
update-alternatives: warning: alternative /usr/share/ghostscript/9.25 (part of link group ghostscript-current) doesn't exist; removing from list of alternatives
update-alternatives: warning: /etc/alternatives/ghostscript-current is dangling; it will be updated with best choice
update-alternatives: using /usr/share/ghostscript/9.26 to provide /usr/share/ghostscript/current (ghostscript-current) in auto mode
Setting up libgs9:amd64 (9.26~dfsg+0-0ubuntu0.16.04.3) ...
Setting up ghostscript (9.26~dfsg+0-0ubuntu0.16.04.3) ...
Setting up cups-ppdc (2.1.3-4ubuntu0.6) ...
Setting up cups (2.1.3-4ubuntu0.6) ...
Updating PPD files for cups ...
Updating PPD files for cups-filters ...
Updating PPD files for foomatic-db-compressed-ppds ...
PPD for printer Lexmark-MX611dhe updated
Updating PPD files for openprinting-ppds ...
Updating PPD files for brlaser ...
Updating PPD files for c2esp ...
Updating PPD files for foo2zjs-common ...
Updating PPD files for gutenprint ...
Updating PPD files for hpcups ...
Updating PPD files for postscript-hp ...
Updating PPD files for ptouch ...
Updating PPD files for pxljr ...
Updating PPD files for sag-gdi ...
Updating PPD files for splix ...
Setting up libcc1-0:amd64 (5.4.0-6ubuntu1~16.04.11) ...
Setting up libgomp1:amd64 (5.4.0-6ubuntu1~16.04.11) ...
Setting up libitm1:amd64 (5.4.0-6ubuntu1~16.04.11) ...
Setting up libatomic1:amd64 (5.4.0-6ubuntu1~16.04.11) ...
Setting up libasan2:amd64 (5.4.0-6ubuntu1~16.04.11) ...
Setting up liblsan0:amd64 (5.4.0-6ubuntu1~16.04.11) ...
Setting up libtsan0:amd64 (5.4.0-6ubuntu1~16.04.11) ...
Setting up libubsan0:amd64 (5.4.0-6ubuntu1~16.04.11) ...
Setting up libcilkrts5:amd64 (5.4.0-6ubuntu1~16.04.11) ...
Setting up libmpx0:amd64 (5.4.0-6ubuntu1~16.04.11) ...
Setting up libquadmath0:amd64 (5.4.0-6ubuntu1~16.04.11) ...
Setting up cpp-5 (5.4.0-6ubuntu1~16.04.11) ...
Setting up libgcc-5-dev:amd64 (5.4.0-6ubuntu1~16.04.11) ...
Setting up gcc-5 (5.4.0-6ubuntu1~16.04.11) ...
Setting up libstdc++-5-dev:amd64 (5.4.0-6ubuntu1~16.04.11) ...
Setting up g++-5 (5.4.0-6ubuntu1~16.04.11) ...
Setting up libgfortran3:amd64 (5.4.0-6ubuntu1~16.04.11) ...
Setting up libgfortran-5-dev:amd64 (5.4.0-6ubuntu1~16.04.11) ...
Setting up gfortran-5 (5.4.0-6ubuntu1~16.04.11) ...
Setting up ghostscript-x (9.26~dfsg+0-0ubuntu0.16.04.3) ...
Setting up libwbclient0:amd64 (2:4.3.11+dfsg-0ubuntu0.16.04.18) ...
Setting up samba-libs:amd64 (2:4.3.11+dfsg-0ubuntu0.16.04.18) ...
Setting up samba-vfs-modules (2:4.3.11+dfsg-0ubuntu0.16.04.18) ...
Setting up samba-dsdb-modules (2:4.3.11+dfsg-0ubuntu0.16.04.18) ...
Setting up python-samba (2:4.3.11+dfsg-0ubuntu0.16.04.18) ...
Setting up samba-common (2:4.3.11+dfsg-0ubuntu0.16.04.18) ...
Setting up samba-common-bin (2:4.3.11+dfsg-0ubuntu0.16.04.18) ...
Setting up samba (2:4.3.11+dfsg-0ubuntu0.16.04.18) ...
Setting up libsmbclient:amd64 (2:4.3.11+dfsg-0ubuntu0.16.04.18) ...
Setting up winbind (2:4.3.11+dfsg-0ubuntu0.16.04.18) ...
Setting up grub-common (2.02~beta2-36ubuntu3.20) ...
update-rc.d: warning: start and stop actions are no longer supported; falling back to defaults
Setting up grub2-common (2.02~beta2-36ubuntu3.20) ...
Setting up grub-efi-amd64-bin (2.02~beta2-36ubuntu3.20) ...
Setting up grub-efi-amd64 (2.02~beta2-36ubuntu3.20) ...
Installing for x86_64-efi platform.
Installation finished. No error reported.
Generating grub configuration file ...
Found linux image: /boot/vmlinuz-4.15.0-39-generic
Found initrd image: /boot/initrd.img-4.15.0-39-generic
Found linux image: /boot/vmlinuz-4.15.0-38-generic
Found initrd image: /boot/initrd.img-4.15.0-38-generic
Found linux image: /boot/vmlinuz-4.15.0-29-generic
Found initrd image: /boot/initrd.img-4.15.0-29-generic
Adding boot menu entry for EFI firmware configuration
done
Setting up grub-efi-amd64-signed (1.66.20+2.02~beta2-36ubuntu3.20) ...
Installing for x86_64-efi platform.
Installation finished. No error reported.
Setting up libssl1.0.0:amd64 (1.0.2g-1ubuntu4.14) ...
Setting up libssl1.0.0:i386 (1.0.2g-1ubuntu4.14) ...
Setting up openssl (1.0.2g-1ubuntu4.14) ...
Setting up python3-distupgrade (1:16.04.26) ...
Setting up ubuntu-release-upgrader-core (1:16.04.26) ...
Setting up ubuntu-release-upgrader-gtk (1:16.04.26) ...
Setting up firefox (64.0+build3-0ubuntu0.16.04.1) ...
Please restart all running instances of firefox, or you will experience problems.
Setting up firefox-locale-en (64.0+build3-0ubuntu0.16.04.1) ...
Setting up flashplugin-installer (32.0.0.101ubuntu0.16.04.1) ...
Setting up git-man (1:2.7.4-0ubuntu1.6) ...
Setting up git (1:2.7.4-0ubuntu1.6) ...
Setting up hwdata (0.267-1ubuntu2) ...
Setting up libwinpr-sysinfo0.1:amd64 (1.1.0~git20140921.1.440916e+dfsg1-5ubuntu1.3) ...
Setting up libfreerdp-primitives1.1:amd64 (1.1.0~git20140921.1.440916e+dfsg1-5ubuntu1.3) ...
Setting up libwinpr-handle0.1:amd64 (1.1.0~git20140921.1.440916e+dfsg1-5ubuntu1.3) ...
Setting up libwinpr-interlocked0.1:amd64 (1.1.0~git20140921.1.440916e+dfsg1-5ubuntu1.3) ...
Setting up libwinpr-thread0.1:amd64 (1.1.0~git20140921.1.440916e+dfsg1-5ubuntu1.3) ...
Setting up libwinpr-synch0.1:amd64 (1.1.0~git20140921.1.440916e+dfsg1-5ubuntu1.3) ...
Setting up libwinpr-crt0.1:amd64 (1.1.0~git20140921.1.440916e+dfsg1-5ubuntu1.3) ...
Setting up libwinpr-utils0.1:amd64 (1.1.0~git20140921.1.440916e+dfsg1-5ubuntu1.3) ...
Setting up libwinpr-pool0.1:amd64 (1.1.0~git20140921.1.440916e+dfsg1-5ubuntu1.3) ...
Setting up libwinpr-registry0.1:amd64 (1.1.0~git20140921.1.440916e+dfsg1-5ubuntu1.3) ...
Setting up libfreerdp-codec1.1:amd64 (1.1.0~git20140921.1.440916e+dfsg1-5ubuntu1.3) ...
Setting up libwinpr-library0.1:amd64 (1.1.0~git20140921.1.440916e+dfsg1-5ubuntu1.3) ...
Setting up libwinpr-environment0.1:amd64 (1.1.0~git20140921.1.440916e+dfsg1-5ubuntu1.3) ...
Setting up libwinpr-heap0.1:amd64 (1.1.0~git20140921.1.440916e+dfsg1-5ubuntu1.3) ...
Setting up libwinpr-path0.1:amd64 (1.1.0~git20140921.1.440916e+dfsg1-5ubuntu1.3) ...
Setting up libfreerdp-common1.1.0:amd64 (1.1.0~git20140921.1.440916e+dfsg1-5ubuntu1.3) ...
Setting up libfreerdp-utils1.1:amd64 (1.1.0~git20140921.1.440916e+dfsg1-5ubuntu1.3) ...
Setting up libwinpr-file0.1:amd64 (1.1.0~git20140921.1.440916e+dfsg1-5ubuntu1.3) ...
Setting up libfreerdp-crypto1.1:amd64 (1.1.0~git20140921.1.440916e+dfsg1-5ubuntu1.3) ...
Setting up libwinpr-input0.1:amd64 (1.1.0~git20140921.1.440916e+dfsg1-5ubuntu1.3) ...
Setting up libfreerdp-locale1.1:amd64 (1.1.0~git20140921.1.440916e+dfsg1-5ubuntu1.3) ...
Setting up libwinpr-dsparse0.1:amd64 (1.1.0~git20140921.1.440916e+dfsg1-5ubuntu1.3) ...
Setting up libwinpr-rpc0.1:amd64 (1.1.0~git20140921.1.440916e+dfsg1-5ubuntu1.3) ...
Setting up libwinpr-sspi0.1:amd64 (1.1.0~git20140921.1.440916e+dfsg1-5ubuntu1.3) ...
Setting up libfreerdp-core1.1:amd64 (1.1.0~git20140921.1.440916e+dfsg1-5ubuntu1.3) ...
Setting up libfreerdp-cache1.1:amd64 (1.1.0~git20140921.1.440916e+dfsg1-5ubuntu1.3) ...
Setting up libfreerdp-client1.1:amd64 (1.1.0~git20140921.1.440916e+dfsg1-5ubuntu1.3) ...
Setting up libfreerdp-gdi1.1:amd64 (1.1.0~git20140921.1.440916e+dfsg1-5ubuntu1.3) ...
Setting up libfreerdp-plugins-standard:amd64 (1.1.0~git20140921.1.440916e+dfsg1-5ubuntu1.3) ...
Setting up libpoppler-glib8:amd64 (0.41.0-0ubuntu1.10) ...
Setting up libraw15:amd64 (0.17.1-1ubuntu0.4) ...
Setting up libssh-4:amd64 (0.6.3-4.3ubuntu0.2) ...
Setting up libssh-gcrypt-4:amd64 (0.6.3-4.3ubuntu0.2) ...
Setting up libunity-settings-daemon1:amd64 (15.04.1+16.04.20160701-0ubuntu3) ...
Setting up libwavpack1:amd64 (4.75.2-2ubuntu0.2) ...
Setting up linux-libc-dev:amd64 (4.4.0-140.166) ...
Setting up linux-signed-generic-hwe-16.04 (4.15.0.42.63) ...
Setting up openjdk-8-jre-headless:amd64 (8u191-b12-0ubuntu0.16.04.1) ...
Installing new version of config file /etc/java-8-openjdk/security/java.security ...
Setting up openjdk-8-jre:amd64 (8u191-b12-0ubuntu0.16.04.1) ...
Setting up perl-doc (5.22.1-9ubuntu0.6) ...
Setting up python-lxml (3.5.0-1ubuntu0.1) ...
Setting up python3-lxml (3.5.0-1ubuntu0.1) ...
Setting up unity-settings-daemon (15.04.1+16.04.20160701-0ubuntu3) ...
Setting up numix-icon-theme (0.3+935~201812050003~ubuntu16.04.1) ...
gtk-update-icon-cache: Cache file created successfully.
Setting up numix-icon-theme-square (18.12.01+201812011517~ubuntu16.04.1) ...
gtk-update-icon-cache: Cache file created successfully.
Processing triggers for libc-bin (2.23-0ubuntu10) ...
Processing triggers for initramfs-tools (0.122ubuntu8.13) ...
update-initramfs: Generating /boot/initrd.img-4.15.0-39-generic
Processing triggers for shim-signed (1.33.1~16.04.1+13-0ubuntu2) ...
No DKMS packages installed: not changing Secure Boot validation state.
```

What can I do?

Answer (score 0):

I think there might be issues with UEFI secure boot. DKMS modules need to be configured to work properly with UEFI Secure Boot.
Why don't you try by disabling secure boot from BIOS and run that command again.

Comment: i follow this commands: https://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=2375583&page=2  ,   dpkg -l | grep linux-     and    dpkg -l | awk '/^rc/{print $2}' | xargs sudo dpkg -P  but i-m not understand if the problem is solved or no

Comment: What about this thread? https://wiki.ubuntu.com/UEFI/SecureBoot/DKMS